# How to get type of component props, when component defined with type parameters

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Although `React.ComponentProps<MyComponent>` is quite handy, I'm unable to figure out how to use it to construct a type of `MyComponent's` props, when `MyComponent` contains type parameters, eg (shortened type taken from a module)

```
declare type TMyComponent = <T = unknown>(props: {foo: string, bar: T}) => ReactElement
```

Somehow, using `TMyComponent`, I'd like to construct the type, eg, `{foo: string, bar: number}`

Although the following doesn't accomplish what I'm trying to do, I hope it demonstrates what I'm trying to do,

```
type MyDesiredType = React.ComponentProps<TMyComponent<number>>
```

How can I construct a type from a component's props that accepts type parameters?

Answer (score 1):

The generic syntax should be near the type, same goes for default type, in your case the "`unknown`" is a default variable in JS syntax.

```
type TMyComponent<T = unknown> =(props: {foo: string, bar: T}) => React.ReactElement

type MyDesiredType = React.ComponentProps<TMyComponent<number>>
// Resolves to
type MyDesiredType = {
    foo: string;
    bar: number;
}

type MyDesiredTypeUnknown = React.ComponentProps<TMyComponent>
// Resolves to
type MyDesiredTypeUnknown = {
    foo: string;
    bar: unknown;
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?&q=360#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQNwCwAUIzAJ5hZwAqAsiwMIlIAOyxCYAHk4A%20OAF4AFGGJhUALjgBvAhAjrUMKMCEBzADRwARsijrOAXwCUcmdjwwAdK-wBRADZYQURhmNg5eABEsVGBKABNOULlMKg8BcAgRMQAFZVRJXjThIPEhAFcQCywoKSlGIA)